# Save vars/objects to YAML file (Spigot)

Tags: java, file, save, yaml, bukkit

I have a few variables of the WE Selection class stored in my plugin. But I would like to use them after the plug-in has closed/restarted. It would therefore require me to save the Selection vars to a YAML file, and then load them in again in the `onEnable`.

```
private Selection sboss;
private Selection s1;
private Selection s2;
private Selection s3;
private Selection s4;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to serialize the Selection and then save it as a String to your YAML file. To regain the same Selection in `onEnable` you will have to write a method that deserializes the String.

For example [CuboidSelection](https://github.com/sk89q/WorldEdit/blob/34c31dc020307a45482ad53ae4d1459b5f653a94/worldedit-bukkit/src/main/java/com/sk89q/worldedit/bukkit/selections/CuboidSelection.java) needs a `World` and two `Location` to be instantiated. You could serialize a CuboidSelection to a String like this: `worldname:x1:y1:z1:x2:y2:z2`

To deserialize the CuboidSelection you get the String from your YAML file, split it at `:`, Get the World via [Bukkit#getWorld(worldName)](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getWorld(java.lang.String)) and parse the coordinates. You can now create two Locations and use them together with the World to get your CuboidSelection back.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can save to a YAML file is Arrays and primitive types so you can't save a whole Selection object. The closest possible thing to what you want is saving the values of the object individually and then setting them by instantiating a new Selection.